# android tabwidget intent tabs refresh every hit

Tags: android, tabs, android-intent, tabwidget

I want to create a tab using child tab having intents, so that when ever user click on tabs intents get refresh.

Every time user click on tab i want to refresh and called oncreate method of child intent tabs.

```
public class Tabs3 extends TabActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1")
                .setIndicator("list")
                .setContent(new Intent(this, List1.class)));

        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2")
                .setIndicator("photo list")
                .setContent(new Intent(this, List8.class)));

        // This tab sets the intent flag so that it is recreated each time
        // the tab is clicked.
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab3")
                .setIndicator("destroy")
                .setContent(new Intent(this, Controls2.class)
                        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Adding `.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)` fulfilled the desired thing.

Comment: thank yo very much , but I hade a problem , when I click on a tab and inside that tab I pressed again on the same tab , nothing happen!!!