# android : Dynamically changing the content of tab

Tags: android, tabs

I want to change the content of a tab?
when tha tab is created i set the content of the tab by setContent() method. But if I click again, I want to change the content that means change to another activity.

I used setOnTabChangedListener() method, but I am not sure about how to set the content to another intent?

```
 Resources res = getResources();
 TabHost tabHost=getTabHost();
 tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("HOME").setContent(new Intent(getBaseContext(),homeGroup.class)));
 tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("ABOUT US").setContent(new Intent(getBaseContext(),aboutusGroup.class)));
 tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

 tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener()
 {  
     @Override
     public void onTabChanged(String tabId)
     {
        //here i want to set the content of each tab to another intent

               // for 'tab1', change to home.class
               // for 'tab2', change to aboutus.class
     //how to set these?                

     }
 });
```

Please help me..
Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

I got solution from the following link :

[android tabwidget intent tabs refresh every hit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370527/android-tabwidget-intent-tabs-refresh-every-hit)

Sorry for disturbing..

Answer (score 0):

You need not to change the content of your activity in a Tab for accommodating new Activity Content.

Instead you need to use ActivityGroup .

Check the link here

[Changing the view within the Android Tab Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734539/changing-the-view-within-the-android-tab-widget/4734670#4734670)

http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html

Hope it helps :)

Comment: my requirement is when i click on the tab, it should load an intent. I have used ActivityGroup in my application, so that, it will load another and another activities. But when I click on the home tab again, i want to load the first activity itself.

Comment: in the activity group there is a stack of activity is maintained. on tab click get each actvity from that stack call finish on each till you reach the first one.